# Unable to print result of comprehension list in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare strings. At the end, I have to capitalize first letter of selected string. In that phase, I'm unable to print result of comprehension list. As a result, code displays list of objects.

```
titres = []
acro = input().lower()
acro = list(acro)
nb_Livres = int(input())

temp =[]
l3 = []
l4 = []


def main():
    for i in range(nb_Livres):
        titre = input().lower().split()
        titres.append(titre)
        if len(titres[i]) == len(acro):
            temp.append(titres[i])

    for i in range(len(temp)):
        titre = temp[i]
        prem_lettre = [0] * len(titre)

    for j in range(len(titre)):
        prem_lettre[j] = titre[j][0]
        l3.append(prem_lettre)
        if acro == l3[i]:
            l4.append(titre)
    x = [[sub_element.title for sub_element in element] for element in l4]
    y = [[str(sub_item) for sub_item in items] for items in x]

    print(y)

main()
```

Comment: so you just want to join the string objects?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] that includes inputs and outputs

Comment: Here are input/output: PP (acronym, input as reference)
7 (number of books)
PEDro paramO (first book title)
Poemes PALINDROMES (sec. book title)
LA Condition HUMAINE (...)
PERE et fils
petite
Promenade Au phare
peter pan/Pedro Paramo (book title selected as first letters correspond to acronym ones)
Poemes Palindromes
Peter Pan

Comment: Please update the question with (formatted) input data. Also, HOW do you want to compare the strings? There's likely an easier solution for the issue you're facing.

Comment: If your data is from a dataframe, please post it by using ```df.head().to_dict()```. It'll greatly increase your chances to get an answer. Otherwise, post other type of data encapsulated inside ``` ```.

Comment: Inputs: 1. acronym (lettres in capital i.e BB for Bed & Breakfast), 2. Number of book for which comparison between acronym and book title mut be done, 3. Titles of books (i.e Peter Pan). Outputs: books for which first letters of title are same of acronym (i.e Peter Pan vs PP => matching case, Peter Pan must be figure as output), first letters of words that compose title must be capitals

Answer (score 0):

Add a parenthesis after `title`:

```
x = [[sub_element.title() for sub_element in element] for element in l4]
```